# Exception when sending big soap request

Tags: exception, soap, wsdl, cxf, wsdl2java

There is a web-service deployed on tomcat 6 and exposed via apache-cxf 2.3.3. A generated sources stubs using wsdl2java to be able to call this service.

Things seemed fine until I sent big request(~1Mb). This request wasn't processed and failing with exception:

```
Interceptor for {http://localhost/}ResourceAllocationServiceSoapService has thrown      
exception, unwinding now org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault:
Error reading XMLStreamReader.
...
com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog 
at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]
```

Is some kind of max request length here, I'm totally stuck with it.

Answer (score 3):

[Vladimir's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5335659/289396) worked. This code below will help others with understanding where to put the 1000000.

```
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault { 
        // Get message content for dirty editing...

    InputStream inputStream = message.getContent(InputStream.class);

    if (inputStream != null)
    {
        String processedSoapEnv = "";
        // Cache InputStream so it can be read independently
        CachedOutputStream cachedInputStream = new CachedOutputStream(1000000);
        try {
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream,cachedInputStream);
            inputStream.close();
            cachedInputStream.close();

            InputStream tmpInputStream = cachedInputStream.getInputStream();
            try{
                String inputBuffer = "";
                int data;
                while((data = tmpInputStream.read()) != -1){
                    byte x = (byte)data;
                    inputBuffer += (char)x;
                }
                /**
                  * At this point you can choose to reformat the SOAP
                  * envelope or simply view it just make sure you put
                  * an InputStream back when you done (see below)
                  * otherwise CXF will complain.
                  */
                processedSoapEnv = fixSoapEnvelope(inputBuffer);
            }
            catch(IOException e){

            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // Re-set the SOAP InputStream with the new envelope

        message.setContent(InputStream.class,new ByteArrayInputStream( processedSoapEnv.getBytes()));

        /**
         * If you just want to read the InputStream and not
         * modify it then you just need to put it back where
         * it was using the CXF cached inputstream
         *
         * message.setContent(InputStream.class,cachedInputStream.getInputStream());
        */
    }       


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured out what was wrong. Actually it was bug inside interceptor's code:

```
CachedOutputStream requestStream = new CachedOutputStream()
```

When I replaced this with

```
 CachedOutputStream requestStream = new CachedOutputStream(1000000);
```

things start working fine.

So the request was just trunkated during copying of streams.

Comment: Where did you add this CachedOutputStream requestStream = new CachedOutputStream(1000000); See i am also   facing  same issue

Answer (score 2):

I run into same issue of geting "com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog" when using CachedOutputStream class.

Looking at sources of CachedOutputStream class the threshold is used to switch between storing stream's data from "in memory" to "a file". 
Assuming stream operates on data that exceeds threshold it gets stored in a file thus following code is going to break

```
IOUtils.copy(inputStream,cachedInputStream);
inputStream.close();
cachedInputStream.close(); //closes the stream, the file on disk gets deleted
InputStream tmpInputStream = cachedInputStream.getInputStream(); //returned tmpInputStream is brand *empty* one
// ... reading tmpInputStream here will produce WstxEOFException
```

Increasing 'threshold' does help as all stream data is stored into memory and in such scenario calling cachedInputStream.close() does not really close the underlying stream implementation so one can still read from it later on.

Here is 'fixed' version of above code (at least it worked without exception for me)

```
IOUtils.copy(inputStream,cachedInputStream);
inputStream.close();
InputStream tmpInputStream = cachedInputStream.getInputStream();
cachedInputStream.close();
// reading from tmpInputStream here works fine
```

Temporary file gets deleted when close() is called on tmpInputStream and there are no more other references to it, see source code of CachedOutputStream.maybeDeleteTempFile()