# Saving outbound messages in CXF interceptor

Tags: java, io, cxf

I have an extremely hard problem for me with CXF, which I'm trying to solve (unsuccessfully) for more than a month. I'd read lots of similar questions, but nothing could help me.

First of all, let me introduce part of the code, which I use to save the outbound messages:

```
  public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
        OutputStream os = message.getContent(OutputStream.class);
        CacheAndWriteOutputStream cwos = new CacheAndWriteOutputStream(os);
        message.setContent(OutputStream.class, cwos);
        cwos.registerCallback(new LoggingOutCallBack());
    }

    class LoggingOutCallBack implements CachedOutputStreamCallback
    {
        public void onClose (CachedOutputStream cos)
        {
            try
            {
                String result = IOUtils.toString(cos.getInputStream());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LogFactory.getLog(SwcFinalResponseInterceptor.class).error(ExceptionUtils.getStackTrace(e));
            }
        }

        public void onFlush (CachedOutputStream arg)
        {
        }
    }
```

I use the **PRE_STREAM** phase. This approach is mentioned in lots of places (for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10501704/1600356)), but it causes some rare errors. I have approximately 20000 requests a day, so, say, for 200 large requests this approach fails - for one of the further requests I get **Stream closed** error.

```
2013-12-19 15:37:47,902 [WARN ] org.apache.cxf.common.logging.LogUtils.doLog(LogUtils.java:400)
5880162-Interceptor for {http://service.ws.swc.comtech/}FrequentFlyerServiceWsService has thrown exception, unwinding now
5880163-org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Stream closed
5880164-        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor.logging(LoggingInInterceptor.java:144)
5880165-        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor.handleMessage(LoggingInInterceptor.java:73)
```

I'm absolutely sure that is because of this line in my code:

```
cos.getInputStream()
```

I've tested lots of times without this only line, and everything worked correct, but when I add this line, errors appear immediately. 
I suppose that's because CXF stores stream data for large streams not in memory but in some temporary file. It was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11669765/1600356).

An interesting point is that when I try to load the testing server by myself, sending thousands of heavy requests with curl, there are no errors, but when there are lots of clients, problems start to appear practically immediately.

I also found [another solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12948702/1600356) and, at first glance, it seemed to work fine, I get no more
**Stream closed** errors, but server starts to skip some responses.

Please, help me, I really don't know what else can I read or do, I'm not good at streams and 
CXF, but I need a working solution and it would be great if you could explain what I'm doing wrong.

If you can't answer this question directly, please, at least, answer some of these questions:

1. Why this line is required **message.setContent(OutputStream.class, cwos);**?
   I don't want to modify stream content, just get what's inside, so why should I read and then send contents again?
2. May be there is more appropriate format (class to get) than this **message.getContent(OutputStream.class);**?
3. May be I should use another interceptor phase?
4. There is a method **onClose**, which is triggered BEFORE stream is closed or AFTER? And when does this happen? I don't want the strem to be closed before it's content is sent as a request to the client.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using spring to configure cxf

Comment: Well, I don't know, because the project was written before me. As far as I can judge, it uses XML file called appContext.xml for confuguration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way I understand your question:

1. If you just want to log SOAP request response envelops, you shouldnt even be using StreamInterceptor. its better to use LoggingInterceptor. To answer your first question 
   message.setContent(OutputStream.class, cwos); intercepts the outgoing soap message and changes the content within it.
2. If you want to continue with StreamInterceptor, you would end up using the same method to get the content of OutputStream. An alternative would be to use LoggingInterceptor.
   for more information on this 
   [How to log Apache CXF Soap Request and Soap Response using Log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8065737/how-to-log-apache-cxf-soap-request-and-soap-response-using-log4j)
3. you can continue using pre-stream. but if the purpose is to just read the message content, you can go with pre_invoke. there is no advantage of using one over another. 
   here is a link which will give you an idea about how could you extend a simple class to implement LoggingInterceptor. 
   http://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html

   [How to get incoming & outgoing soap xml in a simple way using Apache CXF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11038313/how-to-get-incoming-outgoing-soap-xml-in-a-simple-way-using-apache-cxf)

Comment: *its better to use LoggingInterceptor*
Well, my task is to save xml responses to the DB, so logging is not enough.

*intercepts the outgoing soap message and changes the content within it*
I understand that, but I don't want to change anything, just want to read and save.

*you would end up using the same method to get the content of OutputStream*
As I mentioned, that causes some rare errors for huge responses (several megabytes)

I'll try to use the approach from your last link, hope it would help me.

Comment: I am also looking for a solution for this. I have to save interceptor faults into db. I am able to get payload as json/soap. How can I use the same datasource which I'm using for camel-sql component?